# NLog - how to archive log file at day change if there is no new messages

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm configuring NLog programmatically with this FileTarget:

```
var target = new FileTarget(TargetName)
        {
            FileName = Path.Combine(LogDir, "${level}.log"),

            CreateDirs = true,

            ArchiveFileName = Path.Combine(LogDir, "{#}.${level}.zip"),
            ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Date,
            ArchiveDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd",
            ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day,
            MaxArchiveFiles = MaxArchiveFiles,
            OpenFileCacheSize = 5,
            

            KeepFileOpen = true,
            CleanupFileName = false,
            Layout = NLogLayouts.BasicLayout(),
            EnableArchiveFileCompression = true,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };
```

Everythings works as it should be: I have separate log file for each log level.
When a new day starts (22.09.2020) AND some message is written to (e.g., INFO) log, archive is created. Its name is 2020-09-21.Info.zip
At the same moment, my program has no new messages to DEBUG level, and no archive is created before such a message is generated. The problem is that DEBUG level message can be written only in 2-3-or more days, but I want the Debug.log file to be archived at the moment day changed - not when a new message comes.
How can I configure NLog to achieve this?

Comment: Do you really want to keep the log data in memory until the end of the day which is what you are asking?  If you want to archive then move the file to a different folder at end of day.